# How do I export a read_html df to Excel, when it related to table ID rather than data in the code?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am experiencing this error with the code below:

```
File "\<stdin\>", line 1, in \<module\>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

I want to save the table I am scraping from wikipedia to an Excel file - but I can't work out how to adjust the code to get the data list from the terminal to the Excel file using to_excel.

I can see it works for a similar problem when a dataset has data set out as a **'DataFrame'**
(i.e. `df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = \['Product', 'Price'\])`.

But can't work out how to adjust my code for the `df = pd.read*html(str(congresstable))` line - which I think is the issue. (i.e. using read*_html and sourcing the data from a table id)

*How can I adjust the code to make it save an excel file to the path specified?*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

wiki_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_members_of_the_United_States_House_of_Representatives'
table_id = 'votingmembers'

response = requests.get(wiki_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

congress_table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id': table_id})
df = pd.read_html(str(congress_table))

df.to_excel (r'C:\Users\name\OneDrive\Code\.vscode\Test.xlsx', index = False, header=True)

print(df)
```

I was expecting the data list to be saved to Excel at the folder path specified.

I tried following multiple guides, but they don't show the read_html item, only DataFrame solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pandas.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) creates a `list` of tables respectiv dataframe objects, so you have to pick one by index in your case `[0]` - You also do not need `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`, separatly, just go with `pandas.read_html()`

```
pd.read_html(wiki_url,attrs={'id': table_id})[0]
```

##### Example

```
import pandas as pd

wiki_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_members_of_the_United_States_House_of_Representatives'
table_id = 'votingmembers'

congress_table = soup.find('table', )
df = pd.read_html(wiki_url,attrs={'id': table_id})[0]
df.to_excel (r'C:\Users\name\OneDrive\Code\.vscode\Test.xlsx', index = False, header=True)
```